# sensors-detect does not detect

Tags: debian, sensors

I am trying to run sensors-detect in Debian6 64 bits and I get:

> Sorry, no sensors were detected. Either your system has no sensors, or
>   they are not supported, or they are connected to an I2C or SMBus
>   adapter that is not supported.

Sensors applet is correctly running as well as sensor cpu

---

```
    root@debian:/# dmesg | grep -i error 
[ 0.558964] ACPI Error (psargs-0359): [RAMB] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND 
[ 7.537292] PM: Error -22 checking image file 
[ 9.581500] nouveau: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -22
```

---

```
root@debian:/# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point HECI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cougar Point SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 1244 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation Device 0bee (rev a1)
03:00.0 USB Controller: Device 1b21:1042
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Device 1b21:1080 (rev 01)
```

I only get the following running sensors:

```
root@debian:/# sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +27.8°C  (crit = +99.0°C)                  
temp2:       +29.8°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
```

---

**With this proposed script (http://dl.lm-sensors.org/lm-sensors/files/sensors-detect) It seems that sensors-detect find much more, I restart Debian, or I start the service lm-sensor and I get the same outpout at sensors**

Comment: If the sensors are already working then why do you care if the detect script fails?

Comment: The applet shows more than the command line `sensors`?

Comment: Was that an answer to my question?

Comment: That's very confusing. The applet and the command use the same backend, don't they? In any case... try the updated script from http://dl.lm-sensors.org/lm-sensors/files/sensors-detect since the one in Debian is older than your CPU.

Comment: The sensors-detect script only suggests modules to load. You have to put them in `/etc/modules` yourself.

Comment: We are talking about in superuser: sensors-detect does not detect. http://superuser.com/questions/465017/sensors-detect-does-not-detect